# How to get innertext of a Li Using file_get_html

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I have tried to get an Api from MyDramalist but I could not do it.
Now I'm going to extract information from That using PHP.
For example, how can I get the country?

**My PHP Code:**

```
<?php 
$html = file_get_html($id_movie);
foreach ($html->find('.list-item') as $element) {
                        foreach ($element->find("b") as $subelement) {
                            // episode runtime
                            if(preg_match('/Duration/i', $subelement->innertext)){
                                preg_match_all('/[\d](,)?\d*/', $element->plaintext, $matches);
                                $runtime = implode(',', $matches[0]);
                            }

    }
}
?>
```

My PHP code is not correct

**The Output:**

```
2,2
```

**I need This Output:**

```
2hr 2min
```

**MyDramaList HTML :**

```
<div class="box-body light-b"> 
    <ul class="list m-b-0"> 
        <li class="list-item p-a-0">
        <b class="inline">Country:</b>
        South Korea 
        <i class="flag flags-c3"></i>
        </li>    
        <li class="list-item p-a-0">
        <b class="inline duration">Duration:</b> 
        2 hr. 2 min.
        </li>   
        <li class="list-item p-a-0 content-rating">
        <b class="inline">Rating:</b>
        13+ - Teens 13 or older
        </li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
$runtime = $matches[0][0]."hr ".$matches[0][1]."min";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. how can I get the country?